# PHP MYSQL Display results where day is todays date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$today = CURDATE();
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Day ='"$today"'");
```

The columns are:
Name
Day
Time
Reg

And a select * from Persons works fine.

Comment: Are there records in table `Persons`, which should be displayed?
Please, provide your table's schema

Comment: What about $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Day ='".$today."'");

Comment: Thanks thats sorted it :)

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string concatenation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just specify your current date in the query (i.e. no need to calculate in PHP).  This would also give you more consistant time handling in case web server and MySQL server have different timezones.

If `Day` is datetime or timestamp field use this:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Day LIKE CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%')
```

If `Day` is date field use this:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Day = CURRENT_DATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

If `day` is a datetime, then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE Day >= CURRENT_DATE and Day < CURRENT_DATE + interval 1 day;
```

The use of `like` for dates is bad practice, because it requires converting the date to a string.  This prevents an index from being used.

If `day` has no time component, the above will work, but you can simplify it to:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE Day = CURRENT_DATE;
```

You can also write:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE date(Day) = CURRENT_DATE ;
```

(The parentheses on `CURRENT_DATE` are optional.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = CURDATE();
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Day LIKE '$today'");
```